# Create read only user and grant SSH access

Tags: users

I need to create read-only users and make it available for them to SSH with that user name:

1. `groupadd -g 5000 rouser`
2. `useradd -u 5000 -g 5000 -md /home/rouser -c "StrongView Linux User" -s /bin/bash rouser`
3. `passwd rouser`

Is this enough? Do I need to add more info or edit visudo file?

I also noticed that I can log in to their accounts if I have sudo access.

Comment: What do you mean by "read-only" users? Can they write into their home directory? If so, they probably don't need a separate group (just don't add them into the `sudo` group).

Comment: Yes, they can write into their home directory.

Answer (score 6):

By default, users can only write into their home directory (which they own), any location that has 777 access (`/run/shm`, `/tmp`, and a few other places), and any other location that they have user ownership. As long as the user is not in the `sudo` group, the user cannot modify system directories (they can access system directories and files where the `o` octet has the `r` permission).

I recommend that instead of creating a separate group, that you just create the user and place them into the `users` group (which I believe is by default).

Also, the reason you can log into their accounts is *because* you have `sudo` access.